# How to make an image slide on top of another image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to recreate this page: http://www.motorcity.com.bh/offers/subaru using Bootstrap and one of the difficulties i'm facing is the Subaru log on top.

See how it's placed on top of another image in the large screen view? And when you resize the screen to a small size (mobile) it slides to its normal position.

Is it done with css?

If yes, how?

Comment: You can use media query. You have to create custom css styling for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a css class like this:

```
.subaru .navbar-brand.page-scroll {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

change it to this:

```
.subaru .navbar-brand.page-scroll {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: this solution if you want to make the logo position the same as on small screen, but if you want the opposite please notify me because you didn't clarify on your question @vedankita kumbhar